# Equational axiomatization and first-order axiomatization of the class of fields united with the class of Boolean algebras

Tags: field-theory, model-theory, boolean-algebra, universal-algebra

This is really two questions in one, one about universal algebra and one about model theory. Let our signature be $\{+,*,-,0,1\}$. I have recently realized that both fields and Boolean algebras share that same signature. If we interpret $+$ as addition, $*$ as multiplication, $-$ as additive inverse, we get fields, and if we interpret $+$ as union, $*$ as intersection, and $-$ as complementation, we get Boolean algebras. So, now, consider the class $K$ which is the union of the class of fields along with the class of Boolean algebras. My first question is, is there a finite equational axiomatization of the variety generated by $K$, and if so, can someone give me an explicit finite basis? My second question is, is the first-order theory $Th(K)$ generated by $K$ finitely axiomatizable, and if so, can someone give me an explicit finite set of axioms?

Comment: There's a second interpretation for Boolean algebras where we interpret $+$ as symmetric difference; then we get what are called Boolean rings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring). With this interpretation $\text{Th}(K)$ would at least contain the theory of commutative rings which would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My first question is, is there a finite equational axiomatization of the variety generated by $K$, and if so, can someone give me an explicit finite basis?**

The answer to both of these questions is Yes, but I will explain the answer to the first part only and then hint about how to do the second part.

Let $L$ be the language of rings using symbols
$(+,*,-,0,1)$ with arities $(2,2,1,0,0)$.
Let $\mathcal F$ be the variety generated by all fields
in this language and let $\mathcal C$ be the variety of
commutative rings in this language.

**Claim.** $\mathcal C=\mathcal F$.

**Reasoning.**
Since every field is a commutative ring, $\mathcal F\subseteq \mathcal C$.
For the other inclusion, if $R\in \mathcal C$, then
$R$ is a quotient of a free commutative ring $D$.
Free commutative rings, like $D$, are integral domains, so $D$
is embeddable in its field of fractions $Q\in {\mathcal F}$.
Thus, $R$ is a quotient of a subring $D$ of a member
$Q\in \mathcal F$. Since $\mathcal F$ is closed
under the formation of quotients and subrings, $R\in \mathcal F$. \\\

Now let $\mathcal B$ be the variety of Boolean algebras
in the language. The question is whether the variety
${\mathcal V}(K) = {\mathcal B}\vee {\mathcal C}$ has a finite
equational axiomatization.
If we interpret the symbols of $L$ as suggested
by Qiaochu Yuan in his comment on Sep 3, 2023,
then $\mathcal B$ is a variety of commutative rings,
so ${\mathcal B}\subseteq {\mathcal C}$, so
${\mathcal V}(K) = {\mathcal B}\vee {\mathcal C} = {\mathcal C}$.
Everyone knows a finite axiomatization for
the variety $\mathcal C$
of commutative rings, so there is nothing more to do.

But let's return to the original formulation of the problem.
The original post asks that
we interpret $+$ as union and $-$ as complementation
in $\mathcal B$.
With this interpretation, neither $\mathcal B$
nor $\mathcal C$ contains the other. In fact,
${\mathcal B}\cap \mathcal C$ is the variety of
1-element algebras in this signature.
The problem of determining whether
${\mathcal V}(K) = {\mathcal B}\vee {\mathcal C}$
has  a finite
equational axiomatization is now harder.
In general, the join of two finitely based varieties
in the same language need not be finitely based.

Fortunately (for this problem), it is known that
the join of two ***independent*** finitely based varieties
of finite signature
must be finitely based. I don't know any place
where the proof of this statement has been written down
explicitly in the form that is needed here, but it
can be extracted from the
material on pages 20-21 of

O. C. Garcia and W. Taylor
The lattice of interpretability types of varieties. 
Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 50, no. 305, 1984.

or from Section 10.5 of

Ralph S. Freese, Ralph N. McKenzie,
George F. McNulty,
Walter F. Taylor, 
Algebras, Lattices, Varieties: Volume III
Mathematical Surveys and Monographs
Volume: 269; 2022.

Let me explain why $\mathcal B$
(the variety of Boolean algebras in this language)
and $\mathcal C$ (the variety of commutative
rings in this language)
are independent. One establishes independence
of two varieties $\mathcal U$
and $\mathcal V$
by exhibiting a binary 'decomposition term'
$d(x,y)$ in the common language.
This is a term such that
$\mathcal U\models d(x,y)\approx x$ and
$\mathcal V\models d(x,y)\approx y$.
For this problem, the following term works:
$$
d(x,y) = ((1+(-1))*x) + ((-1)*(-1)*y).
$$
One readily verifies that
$\mathcal B\models d(x,y)\approx x$ and $\mathcal C\models d(x,y)\approx y$
using the interpretations of the symbols
given in the problem statement.
In the language of the book by Freese, McKenzie, McNulty, Taylor
that I mentioned above,
this represents
${\mathcal V}(K)$
as the 'inner product' of ${\mathcal B}$ and ${\mathcal C}$
(Definition 10.73).
Then, using their 'standard
equational product axiomatization' of the inner product
(Definition 10.73),
one finds that an inner product of two
finitely based varieties of finite signature
is again finitely based.

**Notes.** Where I say above that ***$\ldots$ it can be extracted from $\ldots$*** I am glossing over some things. The sources cited discuss the 'inner product' of varieties, ${\mathcal U}\vee {\mathcal V}={\mathcal U}\times {\mathcal V}$, only in the setting where every fundamental operation $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ has the property that either
${\mathcal U}\models F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\approx x_1$ or
${\mathcal V}\models F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\approx x_1$. Therefore, if you want to cite their results you must reduce to this setting.
One way to do this is to convert the original signature $(+,*,-,0,1)$ to a different 'derived signature'
$(+_{\mathcal B},+_{\mathcal C},*_{\mathcal B},*_{\mathcal C},-_{\mathcal B},-_{\mathcal C},0_{\mathcal B},0_{\mathcal C},1_{\mathcal B},1_{\mathcal C},d)$ where
$d$ is defined in the original signature by the formula above,
and the other symbols of the derived signature are defined in terms of the original signature as follows:
$x+_{\mathcal B} y:=d(x+y,x)$, and $x+_{\mathcal C} y:=d(x,x+y)$, (and the same pattern of definitions for $*, -, 0, 1$). Then you have ${\mathcal B}\models x_1+_{\mathcal B} x_2\approx x_1+x_2$,
${\mathcal B}\models x_1+_{\mathcal C} x_2\approx x_1$,
${\mathcal C}\models x_1+_{\mathcal B} x_2\approx x_1$, and ${\mathcal C}\models x_1+_{\mathcal C} x_2\approx x_1+x_2$ as needed to apply their results. Another restriction on the results in these sources is that they avoid the use of $0$-ary operations. You can reduce to this case by replacing a $0$-ary symbol like $1$ with a $1$-ary symbol $1(x)$ and adding an axiom $1(x)\approx 1(y)$ which forces $1(x)$ to interpret as a $1$-ary constant function.

Answer (score 3):

Since both the first-order theories of fields and of Boolean algebras are finitely axiomatizable, so is the theory of the structures which are either fields or Boolean algebras. More generally, for any theories $T,S$ the model class of $$\{\varphi\vee\psi:\varphi\in T,\psi\in S\}$$ is always the union of the model classes of $T$ and $S$, and is obviously finitely axiomatizable if both $S$ and $T$ are.

Of course this doesn't address the equational part of the question, since equational logic doesn't allow disjunction, but this does solve the first-order aspect. EDIT: Keith Kearnes has now [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4763626/28111) this much harder question, and this answer should really be considered a footnote to his.